# C++ std::stringstream operator<< vs (constructor)

Tags: c++, constructor, stringstream

My expectation is that I can create an uninitialized `std::stringstream` and feed it a string or just create it with the same stream initially and get the same results. When I did the first case the code was working as I expected. Then I tried the second case expecting there would be the same result which did not happen. What am I missing?

Fragment of the first case.

```
...
int main() {
constexpr auto APTCP_XML_DOC_PREFIX            {R"EOD(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;">]>
<doc>
<head>
</head>
<body>
)EOD"};
   std::stringstream xml_doc; xml_doc << APTCP_XML_DOC_PREFIX;
...
   if (transformer.transform(xml_doc, style_sheet, std::cout) != 0)
      std::cerr << "aptcp/main()/transformer.getLastError(): " << transformer.getLastError() << "\n" << style_sheet.str() << xml_doc.str();
   }
```

Second case has `xml_doc` initialized this way instead.

```
   std::stringstream xml_doc(APTCP_XML_DOC_PREFIX);
```

with this error:

```
Fatal Error: comment or processing instruction expected (Occurred in an unknown entity, at line 2, column 1.)
aptcp/main()/transformer.getLastError(): SAXParseException: comment or processing instruction expected (Occurred in an unknown entity, at line 2, column 1.)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet id="aptcp_stylesheet"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output
            method="html"
            version="4.01"
            indent="yes"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"/>
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet" />
<xsl:param name="current_time_p"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <style>
    pp {display: none;}
    pp, table, tr {
        width: 100%;
...
```

Comment: Seems like the compiler doesn't like the raw string. I'm not sure WHY the compiler would behave differently for the two cases, but it's quite certainly a bug of some kind in this particular compiler. [Although I'm not quite sure if the error is from the compiler or some other tool, it's not entirely clear from your question]

Comment: I was not assuming a bug in the 'compiler or some other tool'. As stated, I do not expected different results so I have assumed I do not understand something. What is it that is 'not entirely clear from your question'?

Comment: What is not clear is whether the error is from the compiler, or the library call you make inside the code. I think it's the latter. In principle, it should not matter which way you set the stringstream. Of course, I'm assuming `...` isn't of importance here - that's not always a safe assumption - for beginner questions, it's nearly ALWAYS the code that was removed that is the problem. Either way, try just printing the value of the string, and see if that produces different outputs - what difference, and can you determine WHY?

Comment: My purpose for posting was to confirm that "the two methods are supposed to be the same", not debug some other issue. I am posting the details to confirm my meaning of the two methods.

Comment: Yes, they are. That's why I immediately said "there's a bug there somewhere".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    constexpr auto BEFORE {"Before"};

    std::stringstream un; un << BEFORE;
    un << "UN";
    std::cout << "un=" << un.str() << "." << std::endl;

    std::stringstream con(BEFORE);
    con << "CON";
    std::cout << "con=" << con.str() << "." << std::endl;
    }
```

shows the value is placed at the front rather than at the end.

```
un=BeforeUN.
con=CONore.
```

To answer the question, the mode is missing ([`std::ios::ate` "seek to the end of stream immediately after open"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream)):

```
std::stringstream xml_doc(APTCP_XML_DOC_PREFIX,
    std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::ate);
```